# A question about the cross section method for triple integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

I learned the following theorem in my multivariable calculus class (I heard it is called the cross section method in English):

> Let $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ be a Jordan measurable region that is between two planes $z=a$ and $z=b$. For $z_0\in [a, b]$, let $V_{z_0}=\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | (x, y, z_0) \in V\}$ be the projection on the $xy$ plane of the intersection between $V$ and the plane $z=z_0$. Then, if $V_{z_0}$ is Jordan measurable, for a continuous and bounded function $f:V\to \mathbb{R}$ we have $$\iiint_Vf(x, y,z)dxdydz=\int_a^b\left(\iint_{V_z}f(x, y, z) dxdy\right)dz.$$

I have two questions:

1. Isn't this just a special case of the following: if we have $\alpha(x, y)\le z\le \beta(x,y)$ for some continuous and bounded functions $\alpha$ and $\beta$ defined on some Jordan measurable set $D$, then $$\iiint_Vf(x, y,z)dxdydz=\iint_D\left(\int_{\alpha(x, y)}^{\beta(x, y)}f(x, y, z) dz\right)dxdy?$$
   I mean, my $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constant functions and this is why I may change the order of integration.
2. When I find $V_z$ if my $V$ is given as the region enclosed by some curves, then I am just keeping the relations involving $x$ and $y$ and those are the equations for my $V_z$ (they may contain $z$, though, about which we know that runs from $a$ to $b$), right?

Comment: No, what you mention in the beginning is not a special case of $#1$. You should think through the example you had yesterday of volume between paraboloid and cone that you solved yourself using cross sections and then I answered with a solution which is what $#1$ here is.

Comment: @MathLover I see, thank you! What about #2? Am I right that this is how you find that cross section in general?

Comment: Yes that is correct. When you integrate over $(x,y)$, you may get a function in $z$ and then you integrate over $z$ from $a$ to $b$.

Comment: @Math Lover thank you very much, that was the part that confused me the most about this cross section method (I kind of failed to see how I actually go about finding that $V_z$ as it was denoted by my lecturer and it seemed like something quite mystical)

Comment: It is interesting to note that due to associativity there are two distinct ways to integrate a triple integral, up to order of of variable, using three iterated integrals - compare a double integral with two iterated integrals. To compute $\iiint_W f(x, y,z)dV$ we can slice the 3-d domain $W$ and sum varying cross sectional areas, e.g. $\int_a^b\left(\iint_{\text{slice}(z)}f(x, y, z) dxdy\right)dz $. Or we can shine a light and project $W$ on to one of the planes (xy,  xz, or yz plane) and vary the last free axis, e.g. $\iint_R\left(\int_{\alpha(x, y)}^{\beta(x, y)}f(x, y, z) dz\right)dxdy$.