# Compute $\displaystyle I=\iiint_V(x+y+z)^2 \, dx \, dy \, dz$, where $V$ is the region bounded by $x^2+y^2+z^2=3a^2$ and $x^2+y^2=2az$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Compute $\displaystyle I=\iiint_V(x+y+z)^2 \,dx \,dy \,dz$, where $V$ is the region bounded by $x^2+y^2+z^2=3a^2$ and $x^2+y^2=2az$.

What I did was I found the intersection of the two surfaces, I got that it is the circle $x^2+y^2=2a^2$ in the plane $z=a$, so I think that $D=\{(x, y)\mid x^2+y^2\le 2a^2\}$ is the projection of $V$ on the $xy$ plane. Then everything is simple because I can easily see that $0\le z\le a\sqrt{3}$, so I should have $$I=\iint_D\left(\int_0^{a\sqrt 3}(x+y+z)^2\,dz\right)\,dx\,dy$$ which is easy to compute by polar coordinates.

However, my book does the following: after finding that the intersection is the circle $x^2+y^2=2a^2$ in the plane $z=a$, it says that $0\le z\le a\sqrt 3$ and it goes on to find the section with the plane $z=\text{constant}$, finding this section to be $x^2+y^2\le 2az$ for $z\in [0,a]$ and $x^2+y^2\le 3a^2-z^2$ for $z\in [a, a\sqrt 3]$. It basically goes on to use the method that I asked about here [A question about the cross section method for triple integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4173652/a-question-about-the-cross-section-method-for-triple-integrals).

I am not really sure if my approach is correct. I kind of understand their approach, but I don't understand why mine would be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ninad Munshi put in his comments, the way question reads, it could mean two different regions. I am considering the region as,

$x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 3a^2$ and $2az \geq  x^2+y^2$.

First find the radius at the intersection of both surfaces.

$x^2+y^2+z^2=3a^2$ and $2az = x^2+y^2$.

$z^2+2az = 3a^2 \implies z = a$. So using cylindrical coordinates, at intersection,

$r^2 = 2az = 2a^2 \implies r = a\sqrt2$.

So integral should be,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{a\sqrt2} \int_{r^2/(2a)}^{\sqrt{3a^2-r^2}} f(x,y,z) \ r \ dz \ dr \ d\theta$

Comment: thank you! I think that this is basically what I did, right? After that projection part I would have used polar coordinates, so this is basically the same as just using cylindrical coordinates from the start

Comment: Great work! Just a footnote however, there are two volumes that the question could be referring to. An inequality on the paraboloid is needed to narrow it down.

Comment: But your bounds of $z$ is incorrect. When you are integrating wrt $z$ first between two surfaces, the bounds will be in terms of $r$ which comes from the equations of the surfaces.

Comment: @NinadMunshi yes based on my experience, I know what the question intends but you are so right which I keep telling all the time in these questions that we should use inequality signs. I will edit my answer at least to clarify that.

Comment: @Math Lover Oh, right, that was really silly of me. It should have been $\iint_D\left(\int_{\frac{x^2+y^2}{2a}}^{\sqrt{3a^2-r^2}}(x+y+z)^2\,dz\right)\,dx\,dy$, right? I don't know why I took those bounds for $z$, probably I was thinking about the other approach by the book

Comment: @TheZone yes that is correct. Just write $x^2+y^2$ in the lower bound as $r^2$ or $r^2$ as $x^2+y^2$ in the upper bound.

Comment: @TheZone yes that is what I was wondering because I had seen you write it correctly in one of the earlier questions. Also use symmetry to simplify your integrand, if you are evaluating integral.

Comment: @MathLover Thanks for confirming that, you've really helped me a lot over the last few days. Any idea why the book decides to use that section method instead of just projecting everything on the $xy$ plane (I noticed that they don't use cylindrical coordinates, so they may have gone about it like this and ended up in the same place)? To me it seemed unnecessarily complicated, this is why I became unsure whether my way really works or not

Comment: You are welcome! Yes if they do not use cylindrical coordinates, at some point they would have to use substitution. Even using cylindrical coordinates, given the way integrand is, one has to do the integral really carefully, use symmetry to be optimal otherwise it can get a bit tedious.

Comment: @TheZone on your specific question why would one use disc method here. It is because the calculations may be a bit tedious but they are elementary whereas integrating wrt $z$ first will require you to integrate $\sqrt{3a^2-r^2} \ dr$...

Comment: @MathLover I see, thank you!

Comment: @TheZone you have two answers and you may want to accept one of the answers provided they helped you.

Comment: @MathLover thanks for reminding me, I was so busy revising for my final exam that I forgot to actually accept some answers that helped me in my preparation

Answer (score 1):

Here is a starting point to help simplify the integrand before you choose a coordinate system to integrate in. Expanding we get

$$(x+y+z)^2 = x^2+y^2+z^2+2xy+2xz+2yz$$

Now there is an ambiguity in the problem - there are two solid regions bounded by those surfaces and you will need specify which is being used. However, both regions share the same symmetry that allows us to say that the integral of the last three terms all vanish since they are odd functions. Thus we can conclude

$$\iiint_V(x+y+z)^2\:dV=\iiint_V x^2+y^2+z^2\:dV$$

This suggests spherical coordinates would be great for the problem, integrating the angular variables first.

Comment: I agree about the ambiguity. Many questions from this problem book that I am using (some local book, not a famous one) have different ambiguities. Anyway, any idea why someone would approach this with that cross section method? It seems way easier to just project $V$ onto the $xy$ plane like I tried to do (and thanks to Math Lover's comment I think that I managed to get the bounds for $z$ right)

Comment: @TheZone by cross sections do you mean integrating w.r.t. $z$ and then figuring out what to do with the other variables later? That's fine if your surfaces happen to functions of $z$ but sometimes the calculation is more tedious then just changing to a different 3d coordinate system. If you have not figured out the spherical coordinates bounds after trying, let me know so I can edit my answer and show you how the calculation simplifies.

Comment: I have, there is no problem with that. I was just kind of curious why would someone do it the way my book did (indeed, they end up with really nasty calculations)